# Get single post detail in angular and ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get single post details but it seems it's returning array of all posts instead on clicked one,

#### Code

`Post service`

```
export class PostsService {

  apiUrl = 'https://example.com/api/posts/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  getPosts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}`).pipe(
      map(posts => posts)
    );
  }

  //getting single post
  getDetails(url) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}?i=${url}&plot=full`);
  }

}
```

`post detail controller`

```
export class PostsDetailsPage implements OnInit {

  post: any;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private postsService: PostsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let url = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('url');
    this.postsService.getDetails(url).subscribe(res => {
      this.post = res;
      console.log(res); //see next part
    });
  }
}
```

`console.log(res); returns`

```
(73) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

`res` in my post controller supposed to return single post detail but it behaves same as my blog page (returning all posts).

`routes`

```
{ path: 'posts', loadChildren: './pages/posts/posts.module#PostsPageModule' },

{ path: 'posts/:url', loadChildren: './pages/posts-details/posts-details.module#PostsDetailsPageModule' },
```

Any idea?

## Update

[image: one]

[image: two]

As you see my back-end works just fine, the issue goes to my front-end functions (shared above)

Comment: You've posted your front-end code but what about your back-end? Is it possible the issues is back-end related? Are you sure you are calling the correct url? Without knowing anything about the back-end it will be hard to help you.

Comment: Maybe i dont see it, but where is the line where you adding the id to each url to lead the GET-Method request to the right URL?

Comment: @liqSTAR i'm using `url (slug)` instead of `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SOLVED

the problem was caused by my get url, I changed it to code below and now working just fine,

```
getDetails(url) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}${url}`).pipe(
      map(post => post)
    );
}
```

I removed `?i=` and `&plot=full` from get part.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your url parameter is undefined. Have you checked your network tab in devtools? There you can exactly see what call has been goin out to the server. Otherwise I would suggest a little refactoring on the point where it is fetched:

```
export class PostsDetailsPage implements OnInit {

  post: any;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private postsService: PostsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((x: {url: string}) => 
      this.postsService.getDetails(x.url).subscribe(res => {
        this.post = res;
        console.log(res); //see next part
      }));
  }
}
```

You should not bee needing snapshot when accessing ActivatedRoute. Also, I would rather use params.subscribe instead of paramMap, because

- You will get route updates automatically
- paramMap is not that reliable (async operations on the route.)